Transfer hook- burn function
Is it possible to get transfer-check when you burn the tokens, for example if I use solincentor to burn the token with transfer hook it would initiate it, also is there any work arounds if its not possible.

This question is similar to: Transfer Hook Program That Collect Transfer Fee to mutiple wallets. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
